# What is the Portuguese equivalent of the Spanish word "ingenio", meaning factory?

Tags: português-brasileiro, tradução, castelhano

The normal word for "factory" in Spanish is *fábrica*.  However, in certain contexts, the word *ingenio* can also be used.  For example, in *La fiesta del chivo*, [Vargas Llosa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mario_Vargas_Llosa) writes in reference to a sugar mill/factory in the Dominican Republic:

> cuando era jefe de guardas campestres en el **ingenio** Boca Chica

Is there a word in Portuguese with the same/similar Latin root that means something like *factory* or *mill*?  I'm particularly curious if Brazilian Portuguese uses a word similar to *ingenio* to refer to sugar cane mills.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, the word is **engenho**. It's only used for sugar mills, and sometimes referred to as *engenho de cana* ("cana" for sugar cane).

As @AndréLyra pointed out below, today, in Brazil, "usina de açúcar" is the most common term for sugar mill.

---

A few facts about the word:

- A very common phrase with this word is *senhor de engenho*, meaning the mill's owner or, by extension, the owner of a vast portion of land and slaves. The term is not used anymore to refer to contemporary mill owners.
- It's featured in the title of a famous 1930's novel by José Lins do Rego, [Menino de Engenho](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/8503010453).
- This is not the only meaning of *engenho*. It also mean *ingenuity*, and has the same root of other words such as *engenharia* (engineering).

Comment: What about fábrica? Is that a synonym? I know it's not the word the OP was looking for but am curious.

Comment: Engenho is used more often than fábrica for sugar mills. For anything else, fábrica is more common.

Comment: Today, sugar factory are called Usinas de Açúcar in Brasil.

Comment: Thanks @AndréLyra, that's true. I edited the answer to point it out.

Comment: Segundo a Wikipedia espanhola o [ingenio azucarero](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ingenio_azucarero) é uma antiga fazenda com instalações para produção de açucar, que foram durante o século XX sendo substituídas por grande *zentrales azucareros*. A melhor correspondência não será *ingenio* = *engenho* e *zentrale azucarero* = *usina de açucar*?

Comment: @Jacinto Possibly